# Can't make JQuery work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

**Tools:** Visual Studio 2010

I'm trying to learn jQuery, but I cant make this example work even after trying for 2 hours.  I know it's quite simple but I don't know what I'm missing.

JQuery is defined here, inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("#divTest1").hide();
            $("p").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div id="divTest1">
        Itz too much I cant make it work...!
    </div>
    <h2>
        This is a heading</h2>
    <p>
        This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>
        This is another paragraph.</p>
    <button>
        Click me</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

**Updates:**

- I have tried this
  $(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello"); });
  And added breakpoint in firebug/Script,after page load firebug got into the jquery library and the went out of it,but it didn't showed any popup
- I just changed from "jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js" to this "jquery-1.7.1.js" and used simple script to check if itz working `$(document).ready( function(){ alert("Hello"); }  );`  ,jquery is working now.

Comment: If javascript was like C#,then compiler must have pointed out the problem :/

Comment: If you put an alert box inside $(document).ready is it called?

Comment: Have you ran it in debug in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox? These tools are invaluable when it comes to JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't `jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js` just the documentation?  Try changing it to `jquery-1.7.1.js`.

Comment: When you load it in a browser, are there any JavaScript errors? Are you *sure* jQuery is being loaded?

Comment: It's working here http://jsfiddle.net/mt3Np/1/, what do you want ?

Comment: What have you done to debug?  When you browse to `Scripts/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js` relative to this HTML, do you see the jQuery code that you would expect?

Comment: @Liath i just tried this $(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello"); }); //But it didnt worked :/

Comment: @dotNetSoldier if the alert box isn't showing then I suspect the problem is with loading JQuery rather than the JS inside it.  I would verify that you have downloaded the file (someone else mentioned vsdoc might be the incorrect file).  Something else you could try is set some regular JS and check whether the $ object is defined.  My suspicion is you've got the wrong library linked or it's not linked correcty

Comment: @Liath check update at the bottom of question,thanks for your concern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Matt Grande, you're not actually including the jQuery library in your page.  You need to add the following to the `head`:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The vsdoc version is just to add Intellisense support.

Also, using [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is preferred over returning false;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#divTest1").hide();
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a return false to the click event of the button, otherwise it will submit the form and refresh the page since you didn't define the button type and it is the only button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#divTest1").hide();
        $("p").hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wefKu/

Comment: or add `type="button"` to the `<button>`.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535211(v=vs.85).aspx) says "The default value of the type attribute depends on the current document compatibility mode."

Comment: I do not believe this is the solution as the $(document).ready is not being called

Comment: @liath I think it is a combination of the two. Without `type="button"` or `return false`, the script still wouldn't work even if the `$(document).ready()` was being called.

Comment: @Liath I was using the vsdoc version of jquery I changed it,and popup is working.

Answer (score 2):

You jQuery is not defined, you have added the Visual Studio jQuery documentation reference and not the actual jQuery library.

Have you tried adding the actual jQuery reference?

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and not

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: vsdoc is only for intellisense ? ,and I may not have to add it at anytime ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#divTest1").hide();
        $("p").hide();

        return false; // after you click, stop the default form action to avoid the redirect
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#divTest1").hide();
    $("p").hide();
});
```

});